# mediaplayer reverb is not working

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to apply reverb effect to mediaplayer by creating a reverb on the output mix (audio session "0" ) , and I use this code

```
    public void reverb1(View v){
    PresetReverb mReverb = new PresetReverb(0,0);//<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    mReverb.setPreset(PresetReverb.PRESET_LARGEROOM);
    mReverb.setEnabled(true);
    mp1.attachAuxEffect(mReverb.getId());
    mp1.setAuxEffectSendLevel(1.0f);

}
```

However when I start the song and apply the effect nothing happens, song continues and reverb effect is not applied. I also added this premission in manifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>`
Still same results, am i doing something wrong?
 I also tried `PresetReverb mReverb = new PresetReverb(0,
mp1.getAudioSessionId());` But still same results.

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PresetReverb mReverb = new PresetReverb(0, mp1.getAudioSessionId());
```

This constructor takes two arguments, first is priority and another one is the audio session id. If u want to reverb than keep ur priority 1 and use global audiosessionId.

```
PresetReverb mReverb = new PresetReverb(1, 0);
mReverb.setPreset(PresetReverb.PRESET_LARGEROOM);
mReverb.setEnabled(true);
mp1.attachAuxEffect(mReverb.getId());
mp1.setAuxEffectSendLevel(1.0f);
```

one more thing to note is that this reverb effects are not supported in some of the devices ...becaz they are having limited equalizer bands. I don't have perfect resources to confirm my state about some devices , but i tested the same on some devices & it's working fine for some and not working fine for some

Comment: Hello, I am facing same problem did you got any solution for this. I am looking for solution for so many days but not got any. Please share your solution to reverb problem thanks in advance and eagerly waiting for your response .....

Comment: it's not working with some devices ...try with sony's phone, it may work

Comment: Can you please share the full code with the media player here.