# No effect with EnvironmentalReverb

Tags: android

I am making application with sound effects attached to MediaPlayer, So I got BassBoost working

```
 BassBoost bassBoost = new BassBoost(0, mp2.getAudioSessionId());
             bassBoost.setEnabled(true);
             BassBoost.Settings bassBoostSettingTemp =  bassBoost.getProperties();
             BassBoost.Settings bassBoostSetting = new BassBoost.Settings(bassBoostSettingTemp.toString());
             bassBoostSetting.strength=1000;
             bassBoost.setProperties(bassBoostSetting);
             if(start2<1000){
                 start2 = (short) (start2 + 100);
                 //setUpBassBostandUI();
                 bassBoost.setStrength((short)start2);
                 System.out.println("short is: "+start2);}
             bassBoost.setStrength((short) start2); 
             mp2.attachAuxEffect(bassBoost.getId());
```

But i cant get Reverb working, I tried PresentReverb and i had no results with it, now i am trying with EnvironmentalReverb and there is no any effect

```
EnvironmentalReverb eReverb = new EnvironmentalReverb(0, mp2.getAudioSessionId());
            eReverb.setDecayHFRatio((short) 100000);
            eReverb.setDecayTime(100000);
            eReverb.setDensity((short) 100000);
            eReverb.setDiffusion((short) 100000);
            eReverb.setReverbLevel((short) 100000);
            eReverb.setReverbDelay(100);
            eReverb.setEnabled(true);
            mp2.attachAuxEffect(eReverb.getId());
            mp2.setAuxEffectSendLevel(1.0f);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check that whatever you're testing on supports it (it is device-dependent). You can use:

```
final Descriptor[] effects = AudioEffect.queryEffects();

// Determine available/supported effects 
for (final Descriptor effect : effects) {
    Log.d(TAG, effect.name.toString() + ", type: " + effect.type.toString());
}
```

I can't remember off-hand if the name prints out something useful. You can find the UUIDs here: [AudioEffect.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/7d1c55fad8194e2c82f5f88f98ab5569f9c52ab9%5E%5E2/media/java/android/media/audiofx/AudioEffect.java)

If it is supported and you are still not hearing anything, you **may** have to apply it to the global audio session to get it working. That's described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16190245/833647).